# doubt in rigging

Tags: animation, rigging, constraints

In the image 1: How can I move the "con eye" under "con root" since in Unity I can only select one root bone?

[image: screenshot for eye/root problem]

In the second image I can see many con cheeks, con teeth, etc. in the dope sheet, but I couldn't see it in the outliner. Is it hidden? How can I see it?

[image: screenshort for cheeks/teeth problem]

Comment: Hi. Seems like you're asking two separate questions here. Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need, but as separate posts.